# DRY when typing a defaultdict

Tags: python, python-typing, defaultdict

Consider a `defaultdict` like so:

```py
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
```

Great. Now I want to add typing info so I get rid of those annoying linter warnings. The type is already *partially* determined as `DefaultDict[Unknown, int]`: on the type of the key is missing.

To type it, I can do:

```
my_dict: DefaultDict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)
```

This repeats a lot of information: the `DefaultDict` and `int` types, just to get the information about the key across.

Is there some way of making this more concise?

Comment: No, there isn't, although, depending on the static analysis tool, the type can be inferred

Comment: It's not repeating information in the sense you think it is. Just because the values will be `int`s doesn't mean the default value will be 0 (which is what `int` as the default factory provides). You might have `my_dict: DefaultDict[str, int] = defaultdict(lambda: 5)`, for example.

Comment: Consider defining a type alias: `DD = DefaultDict[str, int]; ... my_dict: DD = defaultdict(int)`. (Pick a more descriptive name than `DD`, though; it can reflect how the dict will be used rather than just parroting what it is.)

Comment: Also consider whether you can use a `Counter` instead, which is only generic in its key type; the value type is fixed to `int`. You could write `my_dict: Counter[str] = Counter()`.

Comment: Looks like mypy infers `collections.defaultdict[Any, Any]`, and pyright infers `defaultdict[Unknown, int]`

Comment: @chepner - I don't think the default value matters here? Whether I used `int` or some function which returns an `int` of a different value (or even a random value), the type of the value is `int` which is what the type embeds.

Comment: Great tip about `Counter`, I didn't know about this class!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - interesting, I'm using pyright so my observation comes from that angle.

Comment: And what do you expect? Suppose it is inferred to `DefaultDict[Any, int]` from RHS. Now you have to annotate key type (`str`) anyway. When you write `DefaultDict[str]`, it is equivalent to `DefaultDict[str, Any]`, and `Any` here will not be inferred anymore. So you'll end up writing the whole annotation, even if 2nd type argument is properly deduced by type checker.

Comment: @SUTerliakov - I'm not sure what I "expect" but what I want is that I only need to list the key type and the value type continues to be inferred as it already is. Perhaps Python's type system is not able to express this, I'm not sure. I guess one way would be a method which takes the value callable and a type for the key and returns a property typed `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a generic type alias that fixes the value to `int`.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
IntMap = defaultdict[T, int]


my_dict: IntMap[str] = defaultdict(int)
```

Comment: Thanks but it embeds the information that the value type is `Int`, i.e., if I change the RHS to `defaultdict(foo)` I also need to change the typing info.

Comment: Yes, but `defaultdict` doesn't necessarily take a type as an argument at all: it takes a *callable* that produces a value of some time. The type-hinting apparatus doesn't really provide the kind of inference you are looking for.

Comment: Sure it does: as long as the _callable_ has a known return type (which itself comes from inference) it is propagated to the type of the `defaultdict`. I probably confused things by using `int` here and then saying the type should be `int`: instead it could be _any_ int-returning callable and the inference would still work.